# Una pregunta sobre "Rodeábanle"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

En el libro "El Camino a Cristo" me tropecé con esta oración:

"***Rodeábanle** las solitarias montañas y **cubríale** la bóveda celeste con
su manto de estrellas.*"

Entiendo el significado y la traducción de "rodeábanle" y "cubríale". Pero tengo una pregunta sobre su uso gramatical. ¿Realmente se usa así a veces en la vida cotidiana (en vez de decir "*Lo rodeaban las montañas*...")? ¿O solo se usa  en el lenguaje poético?

Comment: En [este enlace](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos) puedes encontrar una detallada explicación de la naturaleza y la posición de ese tipo de pronombres. Aunque se indican algunas formas que se consideran arcaicas, no he encontrado la que corresponde a tu pregunta. En mi opinión, actualmente lo consideraría lenguaje literario, poco usado coloquialmente.

Comment: Sí, gracias. Parece que la explicación está ubicada en este enlace arriba precisamente en punto 3. a)

Comment: @tac yes, it answers my question. Thank you.